# How to make background gradually change colors?

Tags: javascript, background-color

I'm trying to make a web page where the background color of an image gradually changes colors.  I know how to change the background color of something in Javascript, but I don't know how to "animate" it so to speak (without using Flash).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CSS transitions to get that effect. Just add that css code into the element that is changed from js:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

With that on css each time any style value is being changed that change is animated from current to new value by 1s.

It works only on modern browsers. See an example: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/87DZC/17/)

Comment: That actually worked really well.  I just cast an array with a set of colors in JS, and told it to generate a random color from that array every few seconds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example on how to animate the body tag background :

```
function animateBg(i) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(' + i + ', 100%, 50%)';

    setTimeout(function() {
        animateBg(++i)
    }, i);
}
animateBg(0);​
```

Keep in mind that hsl isn't crossbrowser, you can also do the trick with hex/rgb colors.

Jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/euthg/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `setTimeout()` function:

```
function animateBg()
{
  myElement.style.backgroundColor = someNewValue;
  setTimeout(animateBg, 20); // 20 milliseconds
}
```

and invoke animateBg() in your body's `onload` handler. E.g., `<body onload="animateBg()">`.

Comment: You can also use the `setInterval()` function (with same arguments) which will make the "re-arming" your `animateBg()` timer inside `animateBg()` unnecessary (just invoke `setInterval(animateBg, 20)` to have the `animateBg()` function called every 20 milliseconds.

Comment: Either way you really need to add an `if` test to decide whether to continue the animation, i.e., to test whether the background has reached its target colour yet. (And with `setInterval()` you will need an extra variable to keep a reference to the timer id so that you can cancel it, plus `setTimeout()` tends to work better than `setInterval()` with regard to what happens if the user switches to another tab and then comes back later.)

Comment: Good point. I presumed that it was an eternal loop animation for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a [JQuery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). Look at the examples [here](http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/) (click on Demo), they seem to do exactly what you describe.