# How can I make a JS function that can guadually change to a certain color from a similar origin color?

Tags: javascript

eg. I've got a pink color, I want it to change it into red in 3 seconds, the time is the parameter I can alter, the origin and target color are as well.

From this: [How to make background gradually change colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369365/how-to-make-background-gradually-change-colors)

```
function animateBg(i) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(' + i + ', 100%, 50%)';

    setTimeout(function() {
        animateBg(++i)
    }, i);
}
animateBg(0);​
```

I can alter the color, but how can I make similar color and how can I control the time?

Comment: CSS can do that.. answer to your question..

Comment: What did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: I'm stopping this question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```js
function changeColor(){
  document.getElementById("theDiv").className = "red";
}
```

```css
.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

div{
  -webkit-transition: 3s; /* Firefox */
  -moz-transition: 3s; /* WebKit */
  -o-transition: 3s; /* Opera */
  transition: 3s; /* Standard */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv" class="pink"></div>
<button onclick="changeColor()"> Change Color </button>
```

Be aware that the "3s" are in the CSS of the snippet.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp